How to draw circle passing through points in 3D?
Let SABC be a pyramid, the triangle ABC be a right triangle  at B; The line SA perpendicular to the plane ABC; E is  projection point of A on the line SB;  F is  projection point of A on the line SC. How can I draw circle passing through points B, C, E? I tried
Clear["Global`*"];
a = 3;
b = 4;
h = 5;
pA = {0, 0, 0};
pC = {Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], 0, 0};
pB = {b^2/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], -Sqrt[a^2 b^2]/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], 0};
pS = {0, 0, h};
lSB = InfiniteLine[{pS, pB}];
lSC = InfiniteLine[{pS, pC}];
pE = RegionNearest[lSB, pA];
d1 = RegionDistance[lSB, pA];
pF = RegionNearest[lSC, pA] // Simplify;
d2 = RegionDistance[lSC, pA] // Simplify;
\[ScriptCapitalR] = ConvexHullRegion[{pA, pB, pC, pS}];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], 
  FaceForm[{Pink, Opacity[0.2]}], \[ScriptCapitalR],
  Text[Style["A", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, -0.3}],
  Text[Style["B", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {b^2/Sqrt[
    a^2 + b^2], -Sqrt[a^2 b^2]/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], -.3}],
  Text[Style["C", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {Sqrt[
    a^2 + b^2], 0.3, 0}],
  Text[Style["S", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, 
    h + .3}],
  Text[Style["F", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {5/2, 0, 
    5/2 + .3}],
  Text[Style["E", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {80/
    41, -(60/41) + .3, 80/41}], , Thick, Orange, 
  Line[{{pE, pA}, {pF, pA}, {pF, pE}}]
  }, Boxed -> False]

I got

How can I get like this?


reg=Region[Style[
  RegionIntersection[Circumsphere[{pB, pC, pF, pE}], 
   InfinitePlane[pB, {pB - pC, pF - pB}]], Directive@{Cyan, Thick}]]



We can also find the center and radius of such circle.

Solve[{{x, y, z} ∈ Polygon[{pB, pC, pF, pE}], 
  EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, #] & /@ {pB, pC, pF, pE} == r}]


{{r -> 25/(2 Sqrt[41]), x -> 285/82, y -> -(30/41), z -> 40/41}}.


You can do InfinitePlane[{pB, pC, pE}].

@cvgmt When I run your code, I get only a circle. Where I put your code?

Show[reg,......]

@cvgmt Thank you very much.

@cvgmt I have label of two points E and F by hand. How can I put labels automatically?

@JohnPaulPeter  I don't know how to label the points, that is why almost of all my answer does not contain labels.

@cvgmt I tried
Text[Style["F", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"],   pF + {0, 0, 0.3}], Text[  Style["E", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], pE + {0, 0, 0.3}]
